# Combining year date into autofill google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-dates

I am trying to create a basic daily finances tracker using Google Sheets. I want to have it so that yearly tabs reference a template sheet that allows you to change the year on each new tab.

However, I can't figure out how to add a changeable year value in a separate cell to the month and day of the main column and have it autofill out the month and days so that if you change the year it will change the year value down the column.

For example, "01/01/" & A2, would equal 01/01/2022 and still have the option to change the year and have it go all the way through the chart

I have tried using Indirect, and concatenation using & but possibly not correctly, any help would be appreciated

Comment: I can't envision the setup of your sheet. What is the exact range where you want the output? Is the year actually in cell A2? How many dates should be generated: one? Dates for the entire year?

Comment: The year is in A2 seperated from the rest of the date so that it is easily changeable, and dates for the whole year would be generated, so that each day will follow 01/01/year, 02/01/year, Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment on your original post.

That said, assuming you want to generate dates for the entire year number listed in A2:

1.) Make sure you have an empty range that can receive 365 dates (e.g., `A3:A` or `B2:B`).

2.) Place the following formula in the topmost cell of the above output range:

`=SEQUENCE( ("12/31/"&A2) - ("1/1/"&A2) + 1, 1, "1/1/"&A2)`

3.) Select the output range and set the formatting to the date format of your choice (**Format > Number >** ***date format of choice***).

The formula creates a sequence ***x*** rows by ***y*** columns starting at ***z*** (and, in this case, moving by the default increment of 1, which can be set as a fourth parameter in other cases):

***x*** (i.e., number of rows) is found by subtracting the first day of the target year from the last day of the target year and adding 1. Doing it this way is necessary, in order to account for Leap Years.

***y*** is 1 column.

***z*** starts the `SEQUENCE` at the first day of the target year.

This version would produce the same results:

`=SEQUENCE( ("1/1/"&A2+1) - ("1/1/"&A2), 1, "1/1/"&A2)`

Comment: yes that has worked thank you for the assistance

Comment: Great. If you would, please take a moment to mark my solution post as "Best Answer." That helps the contributor community to quickly see which issues have been fully resolved; and it helps future site visitors like yourself quickly find the answers that are most relevant to their own issues.

Comment: With a value of `2021` in cell A2: For the first suggested formula, I'm getting an error message "Function MINUS parameter 1 expects number values. But '12/31/2021' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number." OTOH, the second suggested formula works like a dream. Thoughts?

Comment: I'd have to see it myself, @Tedinoz. (You know how that goes.) Both work for me. If you have a way you feel comfortable with to share a sheet illustrating the issue, I'll take a look. You can always wrap the concatenated dates in `DATEVALUE( )`.